# Is there any tutorial to get feature wise comparision between releases in android

Tags: android

I have developed some application in android 2.2. I have read http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html. But I need to know what are the new features in android 4.0 against 3.0 and 2.2. If there will be any such tutorial which will give details about android features by comparing two old version and latest version, then that will be more easy to remember the feature wise difference between any two releases. Is there any such tutorial which gives version wise comparison between android features.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

Comment: +1 for good response. This link have comparison for user oriented.But i need some thing more developer oriented results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a pre-made API-level comparison (although a change history would include it).

You could always run any of several JAR diff tools, like the one in [depfind](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) (details in the [user manual section](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/Manual.html#APIDifferences)) if you're looking for a summary view. There are a few others, but I'm not as familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just download the code tree, including tags and mount this locally with git/svn/other and use the graphical tools of those csm to explore the code, docs, etc?

I know that it's a bit buggy, but i use eclipse EGIT for that.